# Avada columns are overlapping instead of being one next to the other one

Tags: wordpress

I'm having an issue. As mentioned in the title, when I create any colum 2/3 1/3 or 1/2 1/2 or anything like that the first column is above the other one instead of being next to it.
I made a vidyard video to be clear https://share.vidyard.com/watch/rNAYAU68xvyKbZak8qhZjz?

Can you please help me ?
Thank you !
Anthony

There was no custom CSS added before, nothing has changed. I made all updates of the theme and the plugins and I tried to disable all plugins and just let avada core and avada builder and it's still not working.

Comment: That looks strange. When I add a 2/3 + 1/3 container, the columns are next to each other. Yours behave more like a row. Which Avada version are you actually using? Looks kinda different.